# Azure Availability Sets and adding VM to specific fault domains

Tags: azure, azure-availability-set

So I have 2 classes of VM. Lets call them serverA and serverB.

Within my availability set I want to make sure each Fault domain has 1 of each VMs (ServerA and ServerB). Is it possible to have this level of fine control? From what I can tell it looks like this is achieved by adding the Servers in a specific order i.e. serverA, server A, server B server B assuming I had 2 fault domains.

Is this true? Is it the only way?

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy Virtual machines in an Availability Sets, Azure takes care of placing machines in different fault domains and update domain. We do not have granular level control on deciding which VM needs to be in which Fault domain.

In a high level, if you deploy 2 VMs, then Azure will make sure those 2 VMs are part of different Fault domain and update domain.